# Encountered unknown tag 'load'.?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jinja2

I want to add some custom-template-tags.But, {% load userfilters %} => 'load' tag is not working.

1. settings.py

```py
# project/settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'html/jinja2'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'environment': 'accountv1.jinja2.environment',
        },
    },
]
```

2. jinja2.py

```py
# project/jinja2.py
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.urls import reverse

from jinja2 import Environment


def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': static,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    return env
```

3. app/templatetags/userfilters.py

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter(name='a')
def a(value):
    return 1
```

4. views.py

```py
# use django-rest-framework
class IndexView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({'name': 'max'})
```

5. demo.html

   - is not working

```html
{% load userfilters %}
<!-- custom filter -->
{{ name|a }}
```

- is work

```html
<!-- default filter -->
{{ name|title }}
```

I hope to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `load` tag in Jinja2, and filters work a little differently too (they're just functions).

`templatetags/*.py` is a Django Templates convention, and Jinja2 doesn't use them at all.

You'll want to register your filters where you set up your environment:

```py
def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': static,
        'url': reverse,
    })
    env.filters.update({
        'a': a,
    })
    return env
```

Another option is to use the [`django-jinja`](https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/) template backend instead of Django's built-in Jinja2 backend; it's a little more featureful and [supports `templatetags` style loading out of the box](https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/#_registring_filters_in_a_django_way).