# how to use jinja2 in Django 3.1

Tags: django, jinja2

Now I am using the **Django 3.1** template engine but I am not satisfied with it.

But I see that **jinja2** template engine is very powerful that it.

Thought Django says it has support for jinja2 template engine and I was following [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/) **Django documentation**,
but I couldn't use that.

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

Browser Error:

```
("Encountered unknown tag 'url'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endfor' or 'else'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'for'.",)
```

So, please tell me how do I do it?

Comment: How did you configure the `TEMPLATES` settings?

Comment: You should remove the first one. You can use multiple templates, if you specify with `DIRS` what directories belong to which template. But here both are the same, so that means Django will always select the first one.

Comment: its giving an error that Django admin application requires the Django template engine.

Comment: can you post the exact error. Exactly what page are you rendering. For certain builtin Django apps you indeed need another template. You specify these in the `DIRS` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple engines, but then the directories should be non-overelapping, or you use the engines with a given priority, if you specify with the [**`DIRS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS) what directories belong to which template. But here both are the same, so that means Django will always select the first one.

You thus specify:

```
# settings.py

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    }
]
```

We thus do not add any items to the `DIRS` setting for the `DjangoTemplates`.

Comment: @DevMahdi: can you add the Django backend with `'DIRS': []` (see edited answer).

Comment: @DevMahdi: exactly which template tags? Note that if you register custom template tags, then these should be loaded...

Comment: Encountered unknown tag 'url'

Comment: @DevMahdi: well Jinja does not recognizes `{% url ... %}` and `{% load ... %}`, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55805945/67579

Answer (score 1):

here are docs: https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/

install jinja2

```
pip install django-jinja
```

add into INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
         .......
    'django_jinja',
         .......
)
```

add into template engines list:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django_jinja.backend.Jinja2",
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
           "match_extension": ".jinja",
        }
     },
     {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True
     },
]
```